# What does this syntax mean export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LandingComponent)

Tags: reactjs

A module I have contains the following line. connect seems to have two pairs of parentheses. What does this mean?

```
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps).    
(LandingComponent)
```

Tried to lookup various documentation

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { LandingComponent } from './Landing'

const mapStatetoProps = state => {
  return {}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(LandingComponent)
```

Expect to understand what the syntax means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second set of parentheses is because `connect(..., ...)` returns a function. This function is a component decorator which is why it is called with the landing component class.

If you split it up it might become clearer:

```
const decorate = connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps);
const ReduxConnectedLandingComponent = decorate(LandingComponent);
export default ReduxConnectedLandingComponent;
```

In this case `decorate` is a function that accepts a single component and returns a component. i.e. it takes the plain component and returns a smarter one which pulls props from the nearest provided store in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
const TodoItem = ({ todo, destroyTodo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todo.text}
      <span onClick={destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todo: state.todos[0]
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    destroyTodo: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'DESTROY_TODO'
      })
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem)
```

`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are both pure functions that are provided the stores “state” and “dispatch” respectively. Furthermore, both functions have to return an object, whose keys will then be passed on as the props of the component they are connected to.

In this case, mapStateToProps returns an object with only one key : “todo”, and mapDispatchToProps returns an object with the destroyTodo key.

The connected component (which is exported) provides todo and destroyTodo as props to TodoItem.

Source: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Comment: THanks! Still unclear about this line: ({ todo, destroyTodo }). The flower bracket enclosed tod and destroyTodo. But this does not seem to be a valid JSON object